# Floyd's cycle detection algorithm: Why does the tortoise only do at most one lap?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Why does the Floyd's cycle detection algorithm assume that the tortoise will do at most a single lap around the cycle before it meets with the hare? Why can't it do multiple laps?
Both the intuitive and formal explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you try it with pen and paper, you'll see it at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can provide an intuitive explanation.

We can have two cases: either there is a cycle, or not.

If there is no cycle:

The `hare` will get to the end of the list before the `tortoise` does and so we're done.

If there is a cycle:

It must be of length `n` and we remember that the "speed" of the `hare` is twice that of the `tortoise's`.

 Once the `tortoise` enters the loop, the `hare` is somewhere in the cycle (might have gone around it a few times already). In any case, it is `x` nodes *behind* the `tortoise` (Remember that `x <= n-1` because if they were on the same node we'd end here).

 Since the "speed" of the `hare` is twice that of the `tortoise`, it will "catch up" with it within `x` "steps".

QED.